# building TextTransform files via powershell Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, t4

I simply want to build my t4 files via my azure build pipeline. I tried the following things:

Adding the following powershell script to my solution items :

```
$progFilesx86Path = [System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%programfiles(x86)%")
$vsWherePath = Join-Path $progFilesx86Path "\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"

$textTransformLocation = & $vsWherePath -latest -find **\TextTransform.exe -format value
if (-Not(Test-Path $textTransformLocation)){
    throw "Could not locate TextTransform.exe"
}

Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter *.tt -r | % { 
    & "$textTransformLocation" $_.FullName  -out $_.FullName.Replace(".tt", ".cs")
}
```

This script works fine when I call it with the powershell ISE and actually generates the .cs files in my project, but when I add a powershell task in my pipeline to execute it, nothing happens. My task description looks like:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test.ps1'
```

When I run the pipeline it actually tells me the script has been executed succesfully (It also actually lists all found tt files via the command line), but the .cs files from tt have not been created.

So after that I tried to get my files to build via the visual studio build, adding the following to my project file:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
<PropertyGroup>
   <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
   <!-- Other properties can be inserted here -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

This works when I build locally, but again doesn't generate files when the project is built via the pipeline.

Does anyone know what I am missing here or how I could get this task done?

Comment: Can you show the step where you build your app in the pipeline?

Comment: I tested above powershell script in my test pipeline. It worked fine, the .cs files was created as expected. You can add another powershell task to list  the files in the agent folder to check if the .cs files are there.

Comment: yeh it turns out I was checking the wrong map for my generated files in my build agent and it worked after all. Thnx for the reactions!